# How to print a pdf using python without opening a PDF viewer

Tags: python, pdf, printing

I have a python aplication that creates a pdf using reportlab and print it. The current application just uses Adobe Acrobat to print it using the command:

```
os.startfile('.\\template.pdf','print')
```

What i really want is to print it in python without nedding to use Adobe Acrobat or any other pdf viewer. I just want to communicate directly with the printer.

Is there any way of to do this in python? I would be grateful if someone could help me with this.

Comment: Can you give me an example in python of how to do that, please?